# Facing issues while opening an application via Command Prompt

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

I have an application that would test the HDD performance for me. When I open the application for first time it would ask for Initial setup and I would setup the configurations and save it. Whenever I open the application later on it will show the saved config and pressing enter will open the program. However when I open the program using cmd, suppose if the application is located in **D:\any_folder\app.exe** 
I would enter `D:\any_folder\app.exe`in cmd and it would open the application.

The issue is that when I open the application via cmd, the initial configuration that I saved already doesn't load and asks to setup again. Where as if I open the application using the mouse click it works fine.

I want know if there is anyway to open the application via cmd by loading the config that I saved already ?

I want to open via cmd because I want to write a batch file program to automate the application running.

Comment: Probably your application search for config file in current directory, so you can try something like: `d: & cd \any_folder & app.exe` Or you can try to enter in command line the config file: `D:\any_folder\app.exe D:\any_folder\app.ini`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the batch file itself, travel to the directory via **cd** to the **app.exe** directory, OR place the config file where the batch file is (if you know where it is).

The option of adding the config file as a parameter is unlikely to be supported, since the exe has to be specifically coded to handle that.

I also believe setting up a PATH in the environment variable may allow the exe to access its config file, but I don't have any application on hand to test it, so take this last suggestion with a grain of salt.

Comment: The **cd** method works fine but the location of the file(the directory) is not predefined. I am making it as a user defined getting value from the user. So I tried adding the path in environmental variable option and facing the same issue.